# How to multiply a numeric value with 10 to the value of json in angular7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a json which contains some numeric value(weight),I need to increase all the weight by multiplication of 10 for which is less than 10.I need to get updated json in a console.Here is code below

### home.component.html

```
<div>Hello angular</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],


})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {  

 constructor() {
     }

  ngOnInit() {
       /*this.nestedjson = [
        { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"] },
        { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"] },
        { name: "parent3", value: ["child3"] }
      ];*/

      this.data = [{"name":"Lorem","weight":3},{"name":"Ipsum","weight":2},{"name":"Dolor","weight":10},{"name":"Dolor","weight":20},{"name":"Dolor","weight":30}];


} 


}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? I'm voting to close this until you provide an example of what you have tried to implement to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Lorem",
  "weight": 3
}, {
  "name": "Ipsum",
  "weight": 2
}, {
  "name": "Dolor",
  "weight": 10
}, {
  "name": "Dolor",
  "weight": 20
}, {
  "name": "Dolor",
  "weight": 30
}];

const updated = data.map(item => {
  if (item.weight < 10) item.weight *= 10
  return item
})

console.log(updated)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to first parse your JSON and save it your `this.data` array.

```
this.data = JSON.parse('[{"name":"Lorem","weight":3},{"name":"Ipsum","weight":2},{"name":"Dolor","weight":10},{"name":"Dolor","weight":20},{"name":"Dolor","weight":30}]');
```

Once you get the array of objects, Use the `.map` function to manipulate the data.

```
this.data = this.data.map(i => {
  if (i.weight < 10) {
    return { ...i, weight: i.weight * 10 } 
  }
 return i
})
```

Comment: ```JSON.parse``` is not must

Comment: Yeah, I know. But in all the good practices way, if you are manipulating JSON, you should it first.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it right, you want to multiply by 10 to those weight that is less than 10?

If so, you can do this:

```
const result = this.data.map(item => item.weight < 10 ? { ...item, weight: item.weight * 10 } : item);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Loved this answer Kristy! =)